# Uninstall ubuntu 12.04 and install 11.04

Tags: uninstall, downgrade

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. I have been using it as a dual boot on one laptop with ubuntu 11.04 I believe.

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 on my good laptop as a dual boot and it is really slow. I have plenty of needed memory and graphics and sound to be operating this.

I have read this is an issue and I'm really not sure if I can fix it without literally step by step instructions.  I would like to uninstall 12.04 and install 11.04.

Comment: I just got a little Asus eee (1.6Ghz-2Gb) that came along with ubuntu 12.04 for notebooks. I'm also seriously considering a downgrade back to 11.04 or even 10.04 because twelve is slow and surprisingly irritating. I have already switched back to a gnome ui but there seem to be too many shortcomings in terms of sense and stability.

Answer (score 1):

12.04 has quite serious system system requirements, it was a huge jump from the earlier versions, so that could be a surprise for many users, but downgrade is not possible, as far as I know.

Uninstalling is really simple, just copy all the files you need to your other OS (I guess it's Win), than get a 11.04 installation CD or pendrive, plug to your computer, and boot from it. After few minutes it'll ask, what you want to do, try, or install ubuntu 11.04. Choose install, and when it asks about partitions, choose the advanced mode. Then choose the partition, where the 12.04 lays, click, on it, and choose delete. Then click on Add button, choose the size, the ext4 filesystem, and and the dash mark ( / ) as root. Than click ok, after continue, and it'll install the 11.04, while deleting 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

you can download here all older versions from 8.04 to 12.04

> http://nginyang.uvt.nl/
>
> > or you can install on you old a server for trying new things.
> >
> > > or you try lower you graphics.

Answer (score 0):

İf you get a iso of older version , you can downgrade like a fresh setup.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason that Ubuntu 12.04 runs so slowly is that it has too high of system requirements, you should try a lighter version of ubuntu such as lubuntu, or xubuntu